# How to import code formatting settings from tslint.json in webstorm?

Tags: webstorm, tslint

Is it possible to import formatting settings (`Settings => Editor => Code Style => Typescript`) from my `tslint.json` file in webstorm? I use rules directory `"node_modules/codelyzer"` in my `tslint.json` file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since 2017 **WebStorm** version, it's possible to *Apply code style*.

Just open **tslint.json** and WebStorm will ask if it can import it.

Read it about it in [WebStorm 2017.1 EAP, 171.2455: improved integration with TSLint](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/)

Comment: do you know by a chance how do I force WebStorm to ask me again if I want to import settings from tslint.json once I've already answered 'No' before?

Comment: @markoffden find action (ctrl + shift + a by default) => apply tslint code style rules according to this (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28870). It will be shipped on 2018.2 (unpublished when I write this)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at the moment. You can vote for and follow the updates on this feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19481

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, you can manually apply TsLint settings:

- Find your `tslint.json` file in the Editor or File tree (can also be a `tslint.yaml`)
- Right click the file (again, this can be the Editor pane or the file in the tree)
- Select *Apply TSLint Code Style Rules*. (should be the last option)

The Event Log should be updated with:

```
TSLint: The project code style and editor settings were updated based on 'tslint.json'.
```

More from JetBrains (with pictures): 
[WebStorm Help | Importing code style from a TSLint configuration file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html#ws_tslint_import_code_style)